# What happens to pruned Docker volumes?

Tags: docker

I ran `docker system prune`, forgetting about a particular Postgres database whose contents I still wanted. (It also turns out the macOS Docker VM is not backed up by Time Machine, but that's another question.)

What I'd like to know is whether there is a possibility that the volume has been unlinked, but is still intact and recoverable inside the VM, or whether I should resign myself to recreating the database.

Comment: `docker system prune` does not touch volumes (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/), unless `--volumes` specified

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `docker volume ls` to find out which volumes remain/exist. If you used `docker system prune` without `--volumes` key, it should be there. Creating a postgres container with this volume should bring your database back.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that prune removed volumes, but if not, the one I want is probably still there... there are 75 of them! What's the best way to create a container and associate it with a particular volume? https://superuser.com/questions/1638919/how-can-i-reassociate-a-docker-volume-with-a-container-after-docker-system-prune